# What does this hp led error code mean?

Tags: code, led, hp

I have a HP ProBook 6450b that's been stuck in a boot loop with blinking LEDs going on/off. it sat outdoors, and may have gotten some soil dust inside, not sure, but booted up before that. Basically, the fan and booting sequence starts then stops for seconds, over & over, but the display stays off.

I've changed the CMOS battery and looked up HP LED error codes online, but couldn't seem to find mine, but I am curious to know what the issue is.

[image]

Light 1 is amber and light 3 is blue and light 4 is amber
Light 3 is blue and light 4 is amber,
light 4 is blue

pls, see below screenshot sequence (or, click as it has it):

[blink 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuJ2L.jpg)
[blink 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFpwN.jpg)
[blink 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEAYG.jpg)
[blink 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRRhy.jpg)

Comment: Your screenshots are blurry - I've added a image of the light panel from [the manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02288444.pdf)  and tried to interpret which lights are blinking. If its incorrect feel free to edit my edit.

Comment: Have you try to remove the battery and try to power it?

Comment: i believe i did that initially..

Comment: preciate the image, will try comparing